# Оптимизация функции заполнения массива

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции, циклы, методы

Не знаю, как сделать проще, понятнее функцию countPeopleEyes, которая подсчитывает количество людей с определенным цветом глаз в каждом элементе массива information

```js
let information = [
        {people: [{eyes: 'green'}, {eyes: 'blue'}, {eyes: 'blue'}],},
        {people: [{eyes: 'green'}, {eyes: 'blue'}, {eyes: 'grey'}],},
        {people: [{eyes: 'green'}, {eyes: 'green'}, {eyes: 'grey'}],},
    ];

    let countEyes = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < information.length; i++) {
        countPeopleEyes(information, i);
    }

    function countPeopleEyes(arr, idx) {
        countEyes.push({green: 0, blue: 0, grey: 0});
        arr[idx]['people'].forEach(function (item, k) {
            let eyeValue = arr[idx]['people'][k]['eyes'];
            let arrEyes = countEyes[idx];
            if (eyeValue === 'green') arrEyes.green += 1;
            if (eyeValue === 'blue') arrEyes.blue += 1;
            if (eyeValue === 'grey') arrEyes.grey += 1;
        });
        console.log(countEyes);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let information = [
        {people: [{eyes: 'green'}, {eyes: 'blue'}, {eyes: 'blue'}],},
        {people: [{eyes: 'green'}, {eyes: 'blue'}, {eyes: 'grey'}],},
        {people: [{eyes: 'green'}, {eyes: 'green'}, {eyes: 'grey'}],},
    ];

    let countEyes = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < information.length; i++) {
        countPeopleEyes(information, i);
    }
    console.log(countEyes);

    function countPeopleEyes(arr, idx) {
        let colors = {};
        arr[idx]['people'].forEach(function (item, k) {
            colors[item.eyes] = (colors[item.eyes] || 0) + 1;
        });
        countEyes.push(colors);
    }
```

Comment: Стучатся из функции в глобальную область видимости - плохая практика